# How can I efficiently link two datasets in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class that holds reviews:

```
   public class Review
    {
        public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
        public string RowKey { get; set; }
    }

    IEnumerable<Review> review = // Filled with about 1000 reviews
```

I also have a class that holds the topics:

```
    public class Topics
    {
        public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
        public string RowKey { get; set; }
        public string Topic { get; set; }
    }

    IEnumerable<Topic> topic = // Filled with about 300 topics
```

The first **SIX** characters of the RowKey in Review are the same as the RowKey in Topics.  Partition keys in both cases are an empty string and not used.

I have approximately 1000 records in the review class and 300 records in the topics class.

Is there a good way that I can combine Review and Topics using LINQ to populate the new class below:

```
 public class ReviewGrid
    {
        public string PartitionKey { get; set; }  // PartitionKey from Review
        public string RowKey { get; set; }  // RowKey from Review
        public string Topic { get; set; }   // This would be the Topic from Topics
    }
```

If I do this with LINQ would it take a long time to create and is there a way I could make it create faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a join on PartitionKey

```
var reviewGrids = (from r in review
                   join t in topic on r.RowKey.Substring(0, 6) equals t.RowKey
                   select new ReviewGrid
                   {
                     r.PartitionKey,  
                     r.RoWKey,
                     t.Topic,
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry but Partition key is the same in both and not used. The thing I need to join on is the first six characters of the review rowkey and the topic rowkey.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
IEnumerable<ReviewGrid> rivewGrid = (from r in review
                                    join t in topic on r.PartitionKey equals t.PartitionKey
                                    select new ReviewGrid {
                                       PartitionKey = r.PartitionKey,
                                       RowKey = r.RowKey,
                                       Topic  = t.Topic
                                    })AsEnumerable<ReviewGrid>();
```

Comment: Thanks Elwi. Would this be as efficient as the method suggested by LB. I am looking for something that would run as fast as possible.

Comment: I was writing this when Aducci post it :), but the edited response of Aduccie I think is the best solutions for you, Linq is very fast, I don't know a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var reviewGrid = r.Join(t,
                x => x.PartitionKey + x.RowKey.Substring(6),
                y => y.PartitionKey + x.RowKey,
                (x,y)=>new { x.RowKey,x.PartitionKey,y.Topic  } );
```

Comment: Do you think this would be efficient in joining the 300 rows to the 1000 row table? I am just not sure if one way is more efficient than another.

Comment: @Anne I don't understand. Which ways are you talking about?

Comment: I'm looking at your suggestion and the one by Adduci. They look different but is that just the syntax and will they be the same internally? I have my data sources as IEnumerable<> Is that the best form for them to be in?

Comment: a) `They look different but is that just the syntax and will they be the same internally?` Yes.    b) `IEnumerable<>` is just an interface, in fact, your data is in a concrete class such as List, Array, ObservableCollection etc. and there is no best. Before thinking on performance, first try a few things and if you are not satisfied with the result, then you can start to think on optimizations.